# ¿Como guardar y leer una lista de la BD?

Tags: python, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en **python**, tengo una lista, con la siguiente estructura:

`a = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')...]`

Cada tupla podría tener más elementos, pero ahora son solo dos cadenas.

El problema es que guardo la lista en una BD PostgreSQL, y al recuperar la lista, se carga como cadena de texto y no se transformarla a una lista.

El campo en la BD Postgresql esta como **text** no tome en cuenta el tipo de dato al guardar, pero se puede cambiar. Si tienen ideas... intentare todo llevo todo el día probando código.

Comment: A ver si queda claro, el problema es que la BD devuelve la lista en una cadena de texto, verdad? Entonces `[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')...]` no es realmente una lista, sino texto. Cierto? Y quieres convertirlo en una lista.

Comment: @ArianJM exacto y como dije no considere el tipo de campo al guardar lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Guardar datos en la BD como JSON

Cuando guardes la lista en tu base de datos, deberías guardarla como JSON, y cuando la leas, la parseas como JSON. JSON no soporta tuplas, pero podrás leerlas como listas, que son muy similares, y es probable que no importe si son tuplas o listas.

[Existe un módulo de Python para leer y guardar JSON](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html). Lo que te interesa es: `json.dumps()` convierte lo que le pases a un texto en JSON. Y `json.loads()` convierte el texto JSON que le pases a Python:

```
import json
...
# Para guardar en BD
datos = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
json_a_guardar = json.dumps(datos)
guardar_en_bd(json_a_guardar)
...
# Para cargar de BD
json_leido = cargar_de_bd()
datos = json.loads(json_leido)
print(datos) # Muestra: [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

Ahora bien, si tu problema es que la lista se guarda como cadena de texto en la BD, y eso no puedes cambiarlo, las opciones que siguen te ayudarán a cargar los datos de la BD.

### Usar `eval()`

**Advertencia:** La función `eval()` puede ser peligrosa de usar si no estás seguro de lo que se va a pasar.

Puedes usar la función [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#eval) para evaluar el texto que pases como si fuera Python, así, con la cadena que recuperas de la base de datos, puedes hacer:

```py
lista = eval("[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]")
print(lista[0]) # Muestra: ('a', '1')
print(lista[1][1]) # Muestra: 2
```

De nuevo, ten cuidado con el uso de `eval()` porque si no controlas lo que se pasa ahí, es un agujero de seguridad.

### Convertir en JSON

Y la otra opción que se me ocurre, es convertir esa cadena en JSON válido, a simple vista, con el ejemplo que muestras, bastaría con convertir las comillas simples en comillas dobles, y los paréntesis en corchetes.

```py
import json

texto = "[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]"
texto_json = texto.replace('\'', '"').replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')
lista = json.loads(texto_json)

print(lista[0]) # Muestra: ['a', '1']
print(lista[1][1]) # Muestra: 2
```

### Parsear la cadena "manualmente"

Otra opción, más compleja es parsear la cadena manualmente. Así podrás tener la flexibilidad de hacer lo que deseas. Tendrías que ir encontrando los corchetes y paréntesis e ir creando la lista de tuplas. Podrías hacerlo con expresiones regulares. El código para esto es más complejo.

Comment: si esa parece ser la solucion **json** un poco mas desesperado y me tatuó *json* para recordar lo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy clara tu pregunta, pero vamos comenzando a trabajar con ella a ver si resolvemos:

La variable a que estás declarando, ya es una lista, y cada par ordenado ('a',1') o ('b', 2) son tuplas anidadas.

Ahora bien, para extraer datos de esa lista debes usar la notación de secciónes; si escribes

```
a[0]
```

el intérprete te devolverá

```
('a',1)
```

En caso de que quieras recuperar algún dato de las tuplas anidadas, entonces lo escribirás de la siguiente manera

```
a[0][1]
```

Te devolverá el valor

```
1
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, quedo al pendiente.

Saludos

Comment: ya tupla... el problema es que se guarda como cadena en la BD de postgresql porque nunca tome en cuenta el tipo de dato para el campo (columna) en la tabla

Comment: bueno confuso.... listo **[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')...]** guarda la lista en la BD y recupera como lista muy simple... porque de esa forma porque quiero controlar las **tuplas** repetidas

Comment: Podrias ser más claro con lo que quieres hacer?