# ¿Como guardar una lista en MariaDB?

Tags: python, mariadb, flask, datos

Estoy realizando un app web usando FLask y python 3,

```
lista = [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Requiero guardar los valores de la variable lista en una tabla de MariaDB, específicamente en una columna con las siguientes caracteristicas:
[image: Configuración de la columna donde requiero guardar los valores de la lista]

Espero puedan ayudarme.
De antemano muchas gracias y Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te sirve esta respuesta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440112/80870 También puedes leer sobre [serializar listas](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+list+serialize)

Comment: nota que capaz te sirve: no deberias hacer eso. No tiene sentido... como cambias un elemento de la lista en la db? como buscas dentro de la lista en la db? mas alla de que hay soluciones a lo que pedis, no tiene mucho sentido sistematicamente....